# Wicket 9 - com/github/openjson/JSONException

Tags: json, wicket

I'm upgrading an old Wicket app to Wicket 9. (
"Out of the box", I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/openjson/JSONException

I've included all Wicket 9 Jars in the libraries.

Where this Class should come from ? What did I miss ?

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /misapps/xxxx/: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/openjson/JSONException
at deployment.xxxx.ear.xxxx.war//org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.AjaxIndicatorAppender.<init>(AjaxIndicatorAppender.java:61)
at deployment.xxxx.ear.xxxx.war//org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink.<init>(IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink.java:40)
```

Comment: It seems you don't use Maven/Gradle but you assemble the classpath by yourself. If this is the case then you need to provide the transitive dependencies as well, not just wicket-** jars

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you miss the openjson dependency in your casspath.
If you are using maven, add the following to your pom:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.openjson/openjson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.openjson</groupId>
    <artifactId>openjson</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I included and it's OK. I'm not using maven that's probably why I missed this dependency. Is there a list of dependencies elsewhere ?

Comment: In the pom.xml of wicket i guess ;). I woul suggest you to use maven or gradle for dependency management. It makes your life easier